# Can Perl package instances maintain different variable values?

Tags: perl, oop

My goal was to use the same code to maintain separate variable stacks.  The real sub needs to be called many times, each instance with its own arrays.  My attempt at an object oriented solution has failed:

```
package pkg_magic;
sub new{my $pkg={}; bless $pkg; return $pkg;}

my $keep;
sub set{my $self=shift; $keep=shift;}
sub show{my $self=shift; print"$self $keep\r\n";}
1;
```

Called twice from:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

push(@INC,".");
use pkg_magic;

my $inst1=pkg_magic->new;
   $inst1->set("inst1");
   $inst1->show();
my $inst2=pkg_magic->new;
   $inst2->set("inst2");
# call first instance, not second
   $inst1->show();
exit;
```

Gives output of:

```
pkg_magic=HASH(0x2020f88) inst1
pkg_magic=HASH(0x2020f88) inst2
```

Obviously the same sub is being reached, even though it was called as a different object.  If I copy the package code to separate files and rename the subs (set1, set2, etc) all works as hoped, so I was just trying to simplify code maintenance.  Am I missing something above, or going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Perl classes are different than classes in other languages. You should read [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) to start off with. If you want more details you should read [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html). There are distributions that attempt to hide the details from you though; like [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose), [Mouse](http://p3rl.org/Mouse), [Moo](http://p3rl.org/Moo) there are also others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A package-level variable can only have a single (global) value, but, if you move it into the instance hashref, then each instance can have its own value:

```
package pkg_magic;
sub new{my $pkg={}; bless $pkg; return $pkg;}

sub set{my $self=shift; $self->{keep}=shift;}
sub show{my $self=shift; print"$self $self->{keep}\r\n";}
1;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the scope issue.  The real sub has a bunch of arrays and hashes, and once I started "$self->"ing everything, it became a mess.  Ultimately, I decided to spawn the subs as separate processes and pass the data via sockets.  I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 3):

You must set object attributes *within* the object hash so that they can be independent.

It is also much better to stick to conventional coding standards, especially whe asking for help, so that your code can be easily read by the majority of people. Multiple statements per line are a *bad idea*.

There is also no need to push `.` onto `@INC`: it is already there by default.

**pkg_magic.pm**

```
package pkg_magic;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
  my $self = {};
  bless $self;
}

sub set {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->{keep} = shift;
}

sub show{
  my $self = shift;
  print $self->{keep}, "\n";
}

1;
```

**prog.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inst1 = pkg_magic->new;
$inst1->set("inst1");
$inst1->show();

my $inst2 = pkg_magic->new;
$inst2->set("inst2");
$inst1->show(); # call first instance, not second
```

**output**

```
inst1
inst1
```

Comment: You are correct, I did not need push(@INC,".").  That was an residual of my blind attempts at solving the problem.  Thanks for the input.